# Analog of Visual Studio Solution for my application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, solution

I would like to make an analog of Visual Studio Solution for my application.

I mean to make a file similar to Microsoft Visual Studio Solution file (`.sln`), which includes links to all the other solution files.

Can anyone link to an article on this topic? I could not find anything about it.

Comment: Why solution file itself doesn't suit you ?

Comment: Analog file? Time to pull out ye olde VCR...

Comment: Are you actually going to run build scripts? If so, use msbuild. Or do you just want a file that links to other files? If so, just write a file with some filenames in it.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to build a series of Visual Studio solutions, then you need a build tool.

The two most commonly used in the .NET world are

- MSBuild (reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd393574.aspx)
- Nant (reference: http://nant.sourceforge.net/)

(It's not clear what you're asking, you may wish to clarify or give an example.)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really understand what you mean, but it seems that you need a building system, like CMake (www.cmake.org).